# Reflection with Apache Commons BeanUtils/PropertyUtils: Instantiating for NULLs in Path

Tags: java, reflection, apache-commons-beanutils

I'm using Apache BeanUtils/PropertyUtils to get/set nested properties via reflection. But sometimes, there may be a NULL object somewhere in the tree.

e.g.

```
PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(object, "a.b.c.d", 4);
```

if b is NULL, looking in the code for Apache Commons,

```
if (nestedBean == null) {
         throw new NestedNullException
                ("Null property value for '" + name +
                 "' on bean class '" + bean.getClass() + "'");
}
```

The behavior I'm looking for is instantiation of the missing object to pad the NULLs. Is such a feature available anywhere? Is this called a "Lazy Path" property?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877729/is-it-possible-automatically-instantiation-of-a-nested-property-with-commons-bea

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible automatically instantiation of a nested Property with Commons Bean Utils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4877729/is-it-possible-automatically-instantiation-of-a-nested-property-with-commons-bea)